# cannot execute binary file

Tags: executable, arm

I have a application that gives the error:

```
nhsupsserver: cannot execute binary file
```

I read some texts and the most speak about an architecture mismatch and executable file.

The line that references the error is

```
do_start() {
  $NHSUPSSERVER -d
}
```

I tried with a 32 and 64 bit executable but the same thing happened

```
cubietruck:/usr/local/nhs# file nhsupsserver64
nhsupsserver64: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0x90896f88ce3ae94d53190615abf4f2075ee1b18d, not stripped
cubietruck:/usr/local/nhs# file nhsupsserver32
nhsupsserver32: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=0x5a63e079574fae633eb538a4400f5e6f6e224752, not stripped
cubietruck:/usr/local/nhs# uname -a
Linux cubietruck 3.4.61+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 17 19:28:39 CST 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

What is going on?

Comment: Your shell (and presumably the whole system) uses an ARM processor; it's possible the executable is for a different 32-bit architecture. Try running 'file $NHSUPSSERVER'; if it says something other than ARM (most likely i386, but there are other possibilities), then you need to get a version for 32-bit ARM.

Answer (score 4):

Run `uname -a` and also `file nhsupserver`.  Quite possible that you are running ARM architecture but the nhsupserver binary is for x86.

**UPDATE** now you've added both these outputs it is clear that your hardware is *armv7l* but the nhsupserver binary is compiled for *x86* hardware.

You need to obtain a version of nhsupserver which has been compiled for your armv7l hardware.  This could involve downloading a different package or compiling it from source.  Or abandoning your armv7l hardware and going x86.

Comment: More than "possible": 32-bit binary:  "ELF 32-bit LSB executable, **Intel 80386**", `uname -a` output:   "**armv7l armv7l armv7l**"